# How to fix assignment error using ode45 in MatLab (line 488 of ode45 function)

Tags: matlab, runtime-error, ode45, tspan

I'm trying to write a script that uses `ode45` in order to integrate the **equations of motion of a satellite on an hyperbolic trajectory near Mars**.

I need to integrate the entire passage around the planet: starting from SOI radius (`576000km`) and proceeding towards the planet, then through the atmosphere until the satellite reaches the "`opposite`" atmosphere boundary (set at `250km` from the surface).

When it receives in input a `tspan` higher than about `200000` seconds (I need approximately `400000` seconds), Matlab gives me this message:

> 'Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is
>   4-by-2 and the size of the right side is 4-by-5.' It says that the
>   `error happens in line 488 of Ode45`.

I searched for some similar cases but i couldn't find anything and i don't know how to use **conditional break points** to figure out something on a complex function such as ode45. I also tried different options using "`odeset`" but nothing changed. I have no clue where the error could be.

This is the script, in which i use two additional functions to obtain some of the parameters:

```
Vinf=[2.7 4 6 8];
mu_m=42828;
R_msoi=.576e6;

[afas,efas,pfas]=parasint(Vinf);

an_vera0=zeros(1,length(Vinf));
Vr0=zeros(1,length(Vinf));
Vt0=zeros(1,length(Vinf));

for j=1:length(Vinf)

    c_tstar0=(1/efas(j))*((pfas(j)/R_msoi)-1);
    an_vera0(j)=-acos(c_tstar0);
    s_tstar0=sin(an_vera0(j));
    Vr0(j)=sqrt(mu_m/pfas(j))*efas(j)*s_tstar0;
    Vt0(j)=sqrt(mu_m/pfas(j))*(1+efas(j)*c_tstar0);

end

ti=time(an_vera0,efas,afas,mu_m);

for n=1:length(ti)

    I=(0:3600:ti(n));
    options=odeset('Vectorized','on','RelTol',1e-8,'AbsTol',1e-9);
    [t,Y]=ode45(@(t,y) eqMotoCur(t,y),I,y0,options);

end
```

This is "`parasint`" function:

```
function [afas,efas,pfas]=parasint(Vinf)

mu_m=42828;
R_m=3396.2;
Rp0=R_m+400;
Rpf=R_m+50;
a0=zeros(1,length(Vinf));
e0=zeros(1,length(Vinf));
p0=zeros(1,length(Vinf));
afas=zeros(1,length(Vinf));
efas=zeros(1,length(Vinf));
pfas=zeros(1,length(Vinf));

for j=1:length(Vinf)
    a0(j)=(-mu_m)/(Vinf(j)^2);
    e0(j)=1-Rp0/a0(j);
    p0(j)=a0(j)*(1-e0(j)^2);

    c(1)=p0(j);
    c(2)=Rpf*(1-e0(j)^2);
    c(3)=Rpf*(1-e0(j)^2)-p0(j);
    Efas=roots(c);
    ind=(Efas>1 & isreal(Efas));
    efas(j)=Efas(ind);
    afas(j)=Rpf/(1-efas(j));
    pfas(j)=afas(j)*(1-efas(j)^2);
end
```

This is "`time`" function:

```
function [ti] = time(an_vera0,efas,afas,mu_m)

ti=zeros(1,length(an_vera0));
for j=1:length(an_vera0)
    F=2*atanh(sqrt((efas(j)-1)/(efas(j)+1))*tan(an_vera0(j)/2));
    T=sqrt((-afas(j))^3/mu_m)*(efas(j)*sinh(F) - F);
    ti(j)=-2*T;
end
```

This is the input function for ode45:

```
function [dydt] = eqMotoCur(t,y)
R_m=3396.2;
mu_m=42828;
Cd=2.2;
S=7.065e-6;
m=3699.046;
wE=0.24117/R_m;
if abs(y(1))>R_m+250 && y(3)>0
    dydt(1:4)=0;
else
    dydt=zeros(4,1);
    dydt(1)=y(3);
    dydt(2)=y(4)/y(1);
    dydt(3)=(-mu_m/(y(1)^2))+((y(4)^2)/y(1))-(.5*Cd)*(S/m)*...
    (dens(y(1)-R_m))*(sqrt((y(3)^2)+(y(4)-(wE*y(1)))^2))*y(3);
    dydt(4)=-(y(4)*(y(3)/y(1)))-(.5*Cd)*(S/m)*...
    (dens(y(1)-R_m))*(sqrt((y(3)^2)+(y(4)-(wE*y(1)))^2))*...
    (y(4)-(wE*y(1)));
end
end
```

This is "`dens`" function for interpolation of data through atmosphere:

```
function [rho] = dens(z)

load Density.mat h d
d=d*10^9;

if any(h)==abs(z)
    j=h==abs(z);
    rho=d(j);
elseif abs(z)<250
    c_tot=(find(h>=abs(z)));
    c=c_tot(1);
    H=-(h(c)-h(c-1))/(log(d(c)/d(c-1)));
    rho=d(c-1)*exp(-(abs(z)-h(c-1))/H);
else
    rho=0;
end

end
```

This is the error Matlab gives me:

> Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is
>   4-by-2 and the size of the right side is 4-by-5.
>
> Error in `ode45 (line 488)`
>           `yout(:,idx) = yout_new`;
>
> Error in `MainCur (line 59)`
>           `[t,Y]=ode45(@(t,y) eqMotoCur(t,y),I,y0,options)`;

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- `ode45(@(t,y) eqMotoCur(t,y),I,y0,options)` returns a `5 by 4` matrix
- `[t,Y]`is a `2 by 4` matrix
- Thus dimension mismatch as `5 by 4 # 2 by 4`
- Replace `[t,Y]` by `[t,Y, ~,~, ~]`
- Only keep the first two variables you want, and ignore the remaining
  by using `~`

```
[t,Y, ~,~, ~]=ode45(@(t,y) eqMotoCur(t,y),I,y0,options);
```

Make sure you define `y0` first before running `ode45`

function `dens(z)` should be defined inside `eqMotoCur(t,y)` as you need it to perform some calculations inside `eqMotoCur(t,y)`

```
function [dydt] = eqMotoCur(t,y)
    %% define dens here 
    function [rho] = dens(z)

        load Density.mat h d
        d=d*10^9;

        if any(h)==abs(z)
            j=h==abs(z);
            rho=d(j);
        elseif abs(z)<250
            c_tot=(find(h>=abs(z)));
            c=c_tot(1);
            H=-(h(c)-h(c-1))/(log(d(c)/d(c-1)));
            rho=d(c-1)*exp(-(abs(z)-h(c-1))/H);
        else
            rho=0;
        end

    end
    %% Now start eqMotoCur
    R_m=3396.2;
    mu_m=42828;
    Cd=2.2;
    S=7.065e-6;
    m=3699.046;
    wE=0.24117/R_m;
    if (abs(y(1))>R_m+250 && y(3)>0) ||y(1)==0
        dydt(1:4)=0;
    else
        dydt=zeros(4,1);
        dydt(1)=y(3);
        dydt(2)=y(4)/y(1);
        dydt(3)=(-mu_m/(y(1)^2))+((y(4)^2)/y(1))-(.5*Cd)*(S/m)*...
        (dens(y(1)-R_m))*(sqrt((y(3)^2)+(y(4)-(wE*y(1)))^2))*y(3);
        dydt(4)=-(y(4)*(y(3)/y(1)))-(.5*Cd)*(S/m)*...
        (dens(y(1)-R_m))*(sqrt((y(3)^2)+(y(4)-(wE*y(1)))^2))*...
        (y(4)-(wE*y(1)));
    end
end
```

> The main issue is the time `t`, is quite large if it's evaluated in
>   **second** and that's where ode45 gets stuck. 
> Alternately convert second to **hours(devide it by 3600)**, it will work.  Also the result
>   obtained is struct data type where x denotes t and y denotes y. let's
>   say `t = sol{1}.x` and `y = sol{1}.y`
>  Since the array will be
>   changing every iteration I use a `cell` to keep them separately

## The main code is as follow

```
Vinf=[2.7 4 6 8];
mu_m=42828;
R_msoi=.576e6;

[afas,efas,pfas]=parasint(Vinf);

an_vera0=zeros(1,length(Vinf));
Vr0=zeros(1,length(Vinf));
Vt0=zeros(1,length(Vinf));

for j=1:length(Vinf)

    c_tstar0=(1/efas(j))*((pfas(j)/R_msoi)-1);
    an_vera0(j)=-acos(c_tstar0);
    s_tstar0=sin(an_vera0(j));
    Vr0(j)=sqrt(mu_m/pfas(j))*efas(j)*s_tstar0;
    Vt0(j)=sqrt(mu_m/pfas(j))*(1+efas(j)*c_tstar0);

end

ti=time(an_vera0,efas,afas,mu_m);
ti = ti/3600;
sol = cell(1,4);
for n=1:length(ti)
   y0=[.576e6; an_vera0(n); Vr0(n) ;Vt0(n)];


    I=0:1:ti(n);

    options=odeset('Vectorized','on','RelTol',1e-8,'AbsTol',1e-9);

sol{n} = ode45(@eqMotoCur,I, y0,options);

end
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. It seems that the error happens during intermediate steps regardless of the outputs of `ode45`. When i use a `tspan` lower than `200000` seconds with your modification, it says `Output argument "varargout{4}" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "ode45".` though. I truly don't understand the relation between `tspan` and the assignment error I have.

Comment: Alright, I can't see ```y0``` in your code. Upload ```y0``` I will check it for you

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice. It's in the last `for` cycle of the main script. 
`y0=[.576e6;an_vera0(n);Vr0(n);Vt0(n)];`

Comment: Also define function ```benz``` inside ```eqMotoCur```. I update my answer, check it.

Comment: I need also ```Density.mat h d``` to run the code for you

Comment: Okay, i modified `eqMotoCur` and defined function `dens` inside it, but it keeps giving me the same error. How can I give you `Density.mat h d`?

Comment: Any link where I can download?

Comment: [Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12s1tiHkolsO3F97atDE8mYI3H-MNd5ju/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Updated, check it

Comment: Okay, i tried it and it works now, thank you. But there's another problem: the function is executed as if time is still in seconds and gives me results that are equivalent of just a small portion of the hyperbolic trajectory. In fact the first row of `sol{1}.y` represents satellite distance from Mars center and its values go from `.576e6` to about `.575e6` now.

Comment: I also tried to change the initial conditions in order to use a shorter `tspan` and it seems to show the error everytime `tspan` includes the moment when radius (first row of `sol{1}.y`) cross zero. Can it be caused by divisions for `y(1)` in `eqMotoCur`?

Comment: ```if abs(y(1))>R_m+250 && y(3)>0
        dydt(1:4)=0;``` if ```y(1)== 0``` this condition will be false, I suggest you include it there, check the new update

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was, as you said, in the stopping condition that i manually wrote in `EqMotoCur` function, but considering my purpose I couldn't correct it in the way you suggested: the computation would have stopped in the moment when the radius would become zero.
So, I deleted that condition and I wrote an event function to use as a stopping condition. My modification didn't solve the "division for a possible zero" issue, so I also switched the first two elements of `dydt` and `y` in `EqMotoCur`. In this way, the "computation radius" (`y(2)` or second row in `sol{1}.y` now) will never become neither zero nor lower than Mars radius and the hyperbolic trajectory will be simulated realistically using any value for `tspan` in seconds.
This is the event function I used, if anyone is interested (it's not adapted to the `cell` form because i didn't have time to adapt it):

```
function [value, isterminal, direction] = atmexit(t, y)

    R_m=3396.2;
    value=((y(2)>=R_m+250) && (y(3)>0))-0.5;
    isterminal=1;
    direction=0;

end
```

I could never have done it without your help and time anyway, thank you so much!